# I cannot install nvidia drivers after updating 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I just updated 22.04. Display resolution is busted (fixed at 1024x768). I cannot install Nvidia (or Nouveau) drivers. I tried with Wayland on and off. The installs seem to go to completion, but don't show up (lsmod). Both GUI and CLI approaches were used (with uninstalls that hopefully worked). The Nvidia card is detected.

Along the update/upgrade path, there were 15 (?) packages held back. I didn't want to wait for the hold-backs to be resolved, because the resolution makes the computer unusable; so I used "--upgrade-only" to install them. One package held back was gdm3 . . .

The current (default) kernel is 6.1.0-1008-oem . . .

When trying to start VMware Workstation 17, I was informed that header files were not present when running 6.1 ... and 6.0 ...

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: List the held back packages, who what you see on screen, verify that nvidia driver related packages has been purged, ... without these and similar other things the whole issue is just guesswork.

Comment: Why are you running a 6.x kernel and not the 5.19.xx that 22.04 comes with.

Comment: David: Good question: I am not. I did an update/upgrade yesterday. I was probably running 5.19.xx, but it was whatever was "behind" Ubuntu on Grub (as opposed to Advanced options). It had been a few weeks since I last updated, but was a little surprised to see the 6.x kernels. I am now running 5.19.0-38-generic.

Comment: Hannu: I don't know how to get a list of packages that were held back, before I used "sudo apt install --only-upgrade pkg_name". At this time, all checks that I have performed on the state of packages indicate that all is good. (As far as I can tell.) On verifying removal of nvidia drivers: I followed instructions (from the web) about removing and checking removal of nvidia drivers - I think. But as a follow up: "Nvidia 525" is not used,  but when I tried to install it via CLI, it told me that it was already "up to date".

Answer (score -1):

I am back to having a functional nvidia driver (525) when running 5.15.0-69-generic. I don't know how I got here, but the last few things I did:

1. Used the GUI to (re)install 525.
2. That did not work.
3. Using a suggestion from another Ask Ubunu (from 12/3/22 - the number in the url is 1443757); I reinstalled using the command line. That is

sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-525

and it went off and did quite a bit of work.
4. More importantly, a reboot resulted in a working driver.

I am not at all sure if it will still work if I boot into another kernel, and the 5.15... is way down on the list.

I will open another question about that.

IAC: Thank you for the input.

Tim

Comment: If you want to reference another question on the site cut and paste the ENTIRE URL.